# Permission to grant SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER on all tables

Tags: sql-server, permissions, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2019, azure-sql-managed-instance

In SQL Server 2019, I have created a user defined database role `MyDbRole`.
Now I want to grant following permissions to `MyDbRole` for all tables in the database.

```
CREATE, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER
```

**Question**: What minimal permissions I need to achieve this task. If I were to ask a DBA to give me a permission so I can grant following to `MyDbRole`, what permission should I ask a dba for. I'm guessing, it has something to do with `WITH GRANT OPTION`, but I am not quite sure as to exactly what permission I need?

**Update**: Please note that we are not allowed to use built-in database roles such as db_datawriter, db_ddladmin as these would give more permissions to a user than it's needed). [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#fixed-database-roles)

Comment: A user with those permissions might as well be a DBA with CONTROL permission over the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need those permissions, only the `MyDbRole` needs them - your DBA can grant permissions to this role directly, without you being the man in the middle, by running below code:

```
use [YourDBName]

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [MyDbRole]   
GRANT ALTER TO [MyDbRole]   
GRANT SELECT TO [MyDbRole]      
GRANT UPDATE TO [MyDbRole]   
GRANT DELETE TO [MyDbRole]
```

If you need those permissions as well, your DBA can grant it to you  with grant option, so you can grant permission to your role then:

```
use [YourDBName]

GRANT CREATE TABLE TO [YourLogin] with grant option 
GRANT ALTER TO [YourLogin] with grant option   
GRANT SELECT TO [YourLogin] with grant option      
GRANT UPDATE TO [YourLogin] with grant option   
GRANT DELETE TO [YourLogin] with grant option
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked (thank you). But when I try to revoke `CREATE TABLE` from that `YourLogin`, the same `YourLogin` can still create a table. I have posted a new question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/316860/56185)

Comment: You deserve an upvote. Done.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to create the database role.

You just need to add the user to the following 3 roles:

```
-- db_datareader role will provide SELECT permissions on all tables

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'YourUser';

-- db_datawriter role for DELETE, UPDATE and in addition INSERT

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datawriter', 'YourUser';

-- db_ddladmin role to create and alter objects

EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_ddladmin', 'YourUser';
```

Comment: I have a question posted [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/322496/56185) in case you have time to comment/suggest a possible solution.